non-www URLs and Perch Runway Conflict
all,
First off, I would ask this in the Perch Runway forums, but I have never received an activation code from them to be allowed to do so, and if you know about Perch, you know it's a great CMS, but support is abysmal.
So, I apologize if this is not the appropriate channel, but I appreciate any help this community can provide in advance.
My problem involves redirecting non-www URLs to the proper www URL.  I am certain the issue is with Perch Runway, after having tried every possible variation in my htaccees file.  http://example.com and https://example.com are just refusing to redirect to https://www.example.com; instead landing on Perch's default 404 page.  Plus, after telling Perch Runway the website address is https://example.com (removing the www) it can't resolve any homepage URL at that point.  Forcing https is not a problem at all though.  And the site is accessed via cPanel and through Apache.
Here is my htaccess file as of now, though I've tried it with the sections in the opposite order as well:
Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
Redirect non-www to www and force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
Perch CMS specific rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/perch
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* /perch/core/runway/start.php [L]
And, what's odd is this is just an issue with the homepage.  If I try http(s)://example.com/about Perch Runway finds https://www.example.com/about.  There must be some obscure setting in Perch Runway that is causing the issue, but I'm at a loss.  Any ideas?
